# NAudio: All mixer inputs must have the same WaveFormat

Tags: naudio

I converted a WaveProvider16 to a SampleProvider using Pcm16BitToSampleProvider.  I then added it to a MixingSampleProvider.  The logs did indicate that both are IeeeFloat.  But the program halted at the AddMixerInput line and the error was All mixer inputs must have the same WaveFormat.

Any thought of what I have missed?

```
    myWaveProvider = new MyWaveProvider16();
    mySampleProvider = new Pcm16BitToSampleProvider(myWaveProvider);
    mixerBusWaveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(8000, 1);
    myMixer = new MixingSampleProvider(mixerBusWaveFormat);
    myMixerSampleSource = new MixerSampleSource();

    Debug.WriteLine("mySampleProvider waveformat:  " + mySampleProvider.WaveFormat.ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine("myMixer waveformat:  " + myMixer.WaveFormat.ToString());
    myMixer.AddMixerInput(mySampleProvider);
```

Output:

mySampleProvider waveformat:  IeeeFloat

myMixer waveformat:  IeeeFloat

A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in NAudio.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in NAudio.dll

Additional information: All mixer inputs must have the same WaveFormat

Answer (score 2):

User error: Sample rates mismatched.

This line:

```
myWaveProvider = new MyWaveProvider16();
```

should be:

```
myWaveProvider = new MyWaveProvider16(8000, 1);
```

Otherwise it defaults to 44100.